# How can i replicate results (or find diferences) from keras model with tf.keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I followed a guide to train a model with keras :

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.layers import Dropout
....
```

and got an accuracy result of 0.74.
Then i tried to convert the model to tf.keras , with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
....
```

but the validate accuracy now tops to 0.62.

How can i find what keras does differently so i can do it with tf.keras? (In other SO questions about different results in keras and tf.keras, usaly a reason is given, different default values or parameters. How do i research those differences?)

Installed versions:

```
print(keras.__version__)
print(tensorflow.__version__)
....
2.3.1
2.2.0
```